# MAVROS coordinate system

Tags: ros, coordinate-system, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using mavros with PX4 firmware.
I wonder that the values of the orientation published (in quaternion format) are in which coordinate system.
I'm not meaning NED or ENU but the world coordinate or body coordinate.
Please let me know which one is right?

1. The orientation value is th **body** position in the **world** coordinate system.
2. The orientation value is th **world** position in the **body** coordinate system.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271382/mavros-coordinate-system/) by [NickVot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30327/nickvot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh, the answer is 1

---

Originally posted by [NickVot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30327/nickvot/) with karma: 18 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0